# Why I can't find my Arch Linux on Mac's boot menu?

Tags: arch-linux, boot, usb, macintosh

So I got `Arch Linux` installed on my 128GiB USB under x86_64-efi condition and can successfully boot on my Lenovo laptop (Windows 10 environment).

Later while I plug it into my macbook and hold `option` key while booting to shot boot menu it doesn't shows off the USB. I'm confusing so I plugged my `Arch Linux` installer (the one that'll auto enter root while boot) and it successfully shows up at the boot menu and can boot also.

So I can't understand why I can't find it on the boot menu and how can I solve it?

Comment: Did you install a bootloader (probably Grub?) during the installation? If you set everything up properly, you shouldn't have to enter the boot menu, but a bootloader menu will show up, allowing you to select an os.

Comment: @Matt What? Do you meant bootloader for Mac or Arch? If you meant for Arch, I think yes, I follow the installation guild [here](https://www.tecmint.com/arch-linux-installation-and-configuration-guide/) and if I don't why I can boot on Windows. Also in the tutorial step 24 is a command `grub-install --target=x86_64-efi  --bootloader-id=grub_uefi --recheck` (I'm not pasting all including mounting and pacman install, just paste the grub installation command)

Comment: Ah, misread the question. My mistake. Are you sure grub is installed to the usb stick, not to your (lenovo) laptop? What happens if you try and start that machine without the usb inserted? Do you still see a grub menu? You can take a look at the [official arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installing_Arch_Linux_on_a_USB_key) for their recommendations too.

Comment: As a side note, I would recommend you follow the [installation guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/installation_guide) when installing in the future, as it is kept up to date by the community.

Comment: @Matt I don't see the menu if you meant the menu that you can select Arch Linux or advance option for arch linux.

Comment: Possibly it is an issue with your mac detecting the usb. Do you have another machine you could test this on? Your issue looks somewhat similar to that described [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/162705/macbook-pro-not-detecting-bootable-usb-with-yosemite/163327#163327), perhaps that would be worth a try.